# rails faye server with periodic updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, publish-subscribe

Need to think of the best way to do this.

Im using thin to deploy faye, webrick for the rails app

I have an auctioning site that updates the subscribed channels with information about the latest bids, all done with Faye and Rails.

I need to ensure that the users see the count down to the auction end time with a counter/timer.

If I use JS on the client side to poll for the time left every second, I may end up with 1000 requests per second on the server

I could also use JS to count down only at the client side and then periodically sync the browser every 5 secs per say to ensure that they are sync'd with the server.

Or the other option could be to use faye to publish the countdown to each connected user to the browser

Im a bit concerned of the traffic and want to ensure the user gets to see the correct time of the auction countdown

Logically I think that the client side JS and periodic pushes to sync it would work best.

How do others do this?  Whats the best way?  What other options have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to use Faye as described in this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye).

Polling for changes with JS is probably not an option for you because you have a lot of users. Also the upcoming Rails 4 will allow you to stream server sent events from the controller but this is a little bit experimental yet. [Here](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html) is an explanation of that feature.

If you exclusively want to publish the time left then JS polling not very often to keep sync is an option but very quickly it will become a server load problem as you add new features and users.